# Android Set <String> to array

Tags: android, arrays

I am new to android programming. I have saved my data in`sharedPreference` and get the data back and store as following

```
        Set <String> set = sharedPref.getStringSet(dayName, null);
```

This `Set <String> set` got 3 array stored in a row arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree with a `TAG`. Is there any way to convert it into array and save individually.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

try this example

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("object 1");
set.add("object 2");
set.add("object 3");
set.add("object 4");

String[] array = null;

array = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);

for(String item:array){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

[Anohter related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992807/java-converting-a-set-to-an-array-for-string-representation)

[Set javadic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `Set<String>` into `Array` of `String` as follows...

```
Set <String> set = sharedPref.getStringSet(dayName, null);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
String[] objects = list.toArray();
```